# Why does this async method quit before writing to file?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am trying to get my head around `async/await` and wrote the following console application to download page content of a given URL (based on the [httpclient example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/httpclient) from dotnetperls)

Nothing gets written to the file. What am I doing wrong here?

```
static void Main()
{
    AsyncExample();
}

static async void AsyncExample()
{
    Task<string> task = DownloadPageAsync();
    string result = await task;
    WriteToFile(result, someFileName);
}

static async Task<string> DownloadPageAsync()
{
    string page = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O";
    string result = string.Empty;

    using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using(HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
    using(HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
        result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Does `result` have a value when you use your debugger? If it does then it means your `WriteToFile` method doesn't do what it is supposed to. Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: No exceptions at all. The main thread is finishing before the code can do its work as in the answer from m1o2.

Comment: Have you confirmed that? Because when I execute your code and just print `result` then it gives me the correct behaviour.

Comment: As you mentioned, I was able to print the result, but only if I use `Task.Wait()` on the Main thread.

Comment: The entire point of async/await is to let you write code that _looks_ synchronous, but is actually non-blocking. So your call to AsyncExample in Main returns almost immediately (at the first await), and will continue doing its business on a background thread (broadly speaking). Then, the Main function itself returns, without waiting for the results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because the application is terminated. You need to wait until the AsyncExample finished before letting the main finish it's code.

Currently, the Main method finishes before your task does, and therefore the application is terminated immediately, regardless of the tasks status.

To solve this, you need to wait until the AsyncExample finishes.

One way to do it is to <del>use a continuation and then to</del> wait on this <del>continuation</del> Task using the Task.Wait() method.

<del>We use a continuation for handling errors. Reading the Result property from the original task will throw an exception on error (do that if you want the exception to be thrown here)</del>.

Though, if we didn't use the continuation, and we didn't read the Exception value or the Result from a faulted task, then on finalizing the Task, the application could be terminated. the trick with the continuation handle both of these scenarios.

```
static async Task AsyncExample()
{
    Task<string> task = DownloadPageAsync();
    string result = await task;
    WriteToFile(result, someFileName);
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = AsyncExample();

    task.Wait();
    // task.ContinueWith( t => { }).Wait();
}
```

Comment: That's it. This worked. I just used `task.Wait();` instead of `task.ContinueWith( t => { }).Wait();` and it worked.

Comment: @Nanda OK, that's ok as long you keep in mind that you may get an unhandled exception if you will wait on the original task without a continuation in case of error.

Comment: Sure, I will keep that in mind and look into the continuation mechanism.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, messing around with continuations here is unnecessary. The idea with tasks is that you compose them using async/await or ContinueWith, so they remain non-blocking; and when you want to get the final result, you call Wait on it. And that is where you'll get whatever exception the Task produced, if any. Suggesting adding a continuation to suppress errors here would be like suggesting to wrap method calls in a try block with a catch-all handler. Very rarely, you want to suppress all exceptions... usually you want to know about them, however.

Answer (score 3):

A few things that were too long for a comment on m1o2's answer:

> Though, if we didn't use the continuation, and we didn't read the Exception value or the Result from a faulted task, then on finalizing the Task, the application could be terminated.

1. There is a breaking change in the way unhandled exception behave in the TPL. In .NET 4.0, an `UnobservedTaskException` would terminate your process. In .NET 4.5 it **will not**. For more information on that, see [`this blog post`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5.aspx) by Stephan Toub
2. There is no need for a continuation. When using `await task`, the compiler lifts our code into a state machine which will later run any code after the `await` keyword as a "continuation". If an exception occured inside the awaited task it will be thrown once the task finishes execution.
3. Accessing `Task.Wait` will propogate an `AggregationException`, you dont have to access `Task.Result` or `Task.Exception`. Taken [`from MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Unhandled exceptions that are thrown by user code that is running inside a task are propagated back to the joining thread, except in certain scenarios that are described later in this topic. Exceptions are propagated when you use one of the static or instance `Task.Wait` or `Task<TResult>.Wait` methods, and you handle them by enclosing the call in a try-catch statement.